# Time Discretisation of a System of PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde, eulers-method, discrete-time

Suppose we have an arbitrary system of PDEs

$$ \partial_t u - D_1 \Delta u + a(v) u = f(t)$$
$$\partial_t v - D_2 \Delta v + b(u) v = g(t) $$

We want to discretise the system in time. We use the implicit (backward) Euler method. We put
$$\partial_t u \approx \dfrac{u(t + \Delta t) - u(t)}{\Delta t} = \dfrac{u^{n+1} - u^n}{\Delta t}$$
$$\partial_t v \approx \dfrac{v(t + \Delta t) - v(t)}{\Delta t} = \dfrac{v^{n+1} - v^n}{\Delta t} $$

My question is: when discretising the first equation, for example, which time step of $v$ and $f$ do you consider, i.e. do we write
$$\dfrac{u^{n+1} - u^n}{\Delta t} - D_1 \Delta u^{n+1} + a(v^n) u^{n+1} = f^n $$
or
$$\dfrac{u^{n+1} - u^n}{\Delta t} - D_1 \Delta u^{n+1} + a(v^{n+1}) u^{n+1} = f^{n+1}$$

If both are accepted, is one of them more favourable regarding convergence?

Comment: They can both be used; the first approach would be considered an IMEX (implicit/explicit) method while the second would be considered a fully implicit method. The first approach is easier to implement as it solves a linear algebraic problem for each $n$ (at time $n+1$, you already know the value of $v^{n}$). The latter approach is more difficult to implement as it solves a nonlinear algebraic problem for each $n$ and requires the use of a root finding algorithm like Newton iteration, but is more robust as implicit solvers can usually handle stiff problems that explicit solvers can't.

Comment: Also, just so you know, there is a [specific stackexchange site dedicated to scientific computing](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).